# High Charts Grid Lines Not displaying Correctly

Tags: highcharts

We have a large web application that we are using High Charts in. We use Bootstrap, Jquery and some other plugins.

The issue is that the grid lines are not showing up correctly. The application is pretty large and I cannot recreate the issue in a fiddle. I basically copy and pasted the code from a demo fiddle for testing so the code should be good.

As requested, here is the example fiddle of what I am trying to achieve: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k96xwnnj/5/) I tried to move it outside all elements except the body and still have the issue.

Here is a screenshot.[image: fiddle]

Here is the code I have on my page. i will be switching to json loading the data,  but I need to get the rendering correct before I spend the time on that.

```
 $(function ()
{
    $('#ChartContainer2').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'bar',
            options3d: {
                enabled: true,
                alpha: 20,
                beta: 20,
                viewDistance: 0,
                depth: 60
            },
            marginTop: 80,
            marginRight: 40
        },

        title: {
            text: ''
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['15-05 SFYBAKE Brooklyn Bred - Bakery Rack Display (NOR) Brooklyn Bred Rack in Bakery',
                         '10-10 Savemart- Lucky 5 Hour Diet HBC resets Savemart-Lucky 5 Hour Diet HBC Resets',
                         '11-10 SFY 5 HOUR Energy CMT Dist. Check 5 HOUR Energy CMT Dist. Check',
                         '10-07 SFY 5 Hour Energy Drink 5 Hour Energy Drink',

            ]
        },

        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Percent Complete'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{point.key}</b><br>',
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: {point.y} / {point.stackTotal}'
        },

        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                depth: 10

            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 3, 4],

        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [3, 2, 1],

        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [2, 5, 6],

        }]
    });
```

Comment: Can you at least post your highcharts options and create a representative live example?

Comment: I added my current  code and added a link to the example of what I am trying to achieve. They're almost exactly the same.

Comment: Your jsFiddle looks OK to me. Perhaps there is some other conflict with other items in your page?

Comment: yeah, I've tried removing all css and js except needed and still having the issue. I may need to just go another direction. thank you for your time.

Comment: Make sure you are using latest version of highcharts libraries is the only other thing I can suggest.

Comment: I'll make sure thanks. To be clear, to have two highcharts on one page, I just need different container id's right?

Comment: Correct. You need an distinct container for each.

Comment: See I have that. If I remove my pie chart the bar graph displays correctly. But with both on the page the colors are off and the gridlines are aswell.

Comment: Do you have any shared components between the pie and bar chart? Any global options that both use? Can you put up a sample pie chart in your jsFiddle to go along with the 3D chart?

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion! I got it working. I was using this to set the colors,   Highcharts.setOptions({ colors: ['#F3E1E1', '#A6DFAF', '#ED561B']  }); and after I removed it now both work and the grids display correctly. I'm still not sure why.

Comment: It would depend on where you applied setOptions in the code logic. You might have confused highcharts or jQuery if the implementation order was off.

Comment: That makes sense. Well thank you for your help. I would mark you as the answer if you had posted one. You still can if you want.